# Mod rewrite directory to subdomain (not the more common other way around)

Tags: regex, wordpress, mod-rewrite

When a user goes to example.com/page/-/filename.extension, I want them to see the file at m.example.com/page/-/filename.extension without a visible redirect. (I want all img src="http://example.com/page/-/..." references on my site to continue to work, though files are now hosted on m.example.com.)

I've tried dozens of permutations and but can't figure it out. What should this be?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com/page/-/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page/-/(.*)$ http://m.example.com/page/-/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not be possible without redirect using rewrite rules.

You can either make permanent redirect R=301 using rewrite rules.

Or if you want to avoid permanent redirect , you can use [proxy_pass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

Comment: Does this mean there is no way to keep img tags with old URLs intact? I don't think I can use proxy_pass because I am on a shared server in which I think it's deactivated.

Comment: only with redirect , its possible

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't prevent a visible redirect, but I've tested and it does keep `img` tags intact:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/page/-/(.*)$ http://m.example.com/page/-/$1
```

Not sure if it needs any flags.

Comment: After more usage I'm finding that this doesn't work with timthumb.php.